# RPC Error 1722 from IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, rpc, domaincontroller

MQ queue manager is not able to start and in logs we see the error RPC server unavailable. The account that we are using is a domain account `<domain>\<accountName>`. When we use the `netuser` command with domain's FQDN, we get the groups that it belong to like `<domain.dummy.com>\<accountName>`. But when we do the same like `<domain>\<accountName>` then we don't get any response back. any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen an error like this that had to so with the DNS configuration.  I think we had to go to the DNS settings and add each domain to the search path, ex: `domain.dummy.com` instead of just `dummy.com`.

Comment: That's a Windows error rather than an MQ error. I can confirm this by searching for "RPC server unavailable" on the wider internet.